# SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier Error when running React app in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on React app with webpack and babel. When running it on IE11 "SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier" error messages appear. I've solved most of these errors (e.g I've added @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions to my webpack configuration to solve the problem with arrow functions on IE11).

There is still one error with message "SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier". In the console this line is marked:

```
r=function(r,i){for(var c,l,[a,u,s,f]=i,p=0,b=[];p<a.length;p++)
```

and the cursor is positioned before the first opening bracket. I think the problem is with [a,u,s,f]=i. Do I need any additional babel plugin?

Here is a fragment of my webpack config:

```
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: [
          ['@babel/preset-env', { 'targets': { 'ie': '11'} }],
          '@babel/preset-react'
        ],
        plugins: [
          ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true }],
          ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { 'loose': true }],
          ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'],
          ['@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions']
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Some times app gets render using the IE 7 document mode that can cause this kind of errors. I suggest you try to check in which document mode your app getting rendered and if it gets rendered in IE 7 mode then try to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in your app to make sure it uses the IE 11 document mode.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted in official React docs:

> If you support older browsers and devices which may not yet provide
> these natively (e.g. IE < 11) or which have non-compliant
> implementations (e.g. IE 11), consider including a global polyfill in
> your bundled application, such as core-js.

You need polyfill such as core-js for mapping and setting variables in your code .
Check it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html

Comment: I've installed **core-js@3.9.0**, added **import 'core-js';** in index.js (my entry point) and changed **['@babel/preset-env', { 'targets': { 'ie': '11'} }],** to  **['@babel/preset-env', { 'targets': { 'ie': '11'}, 'useBuiltIns': 'entry', 'corejs': { 'version': '3.9', 'proposals': true }}]** in webpack.config.js. The problem still exists in the same place.

Comment: @blasphemy did you find a solution for this ?